# WinUSB failing on non-development computers

Tags: windows, visual-c++, usb, winusb

Good afternoon,

WinUSB is working well on the development computer that I am using (Win XP SP3).  I am able to download new firmware to the Cypress FX2, and then connect to the new USB device once it 'renumerates'.  However, if I've tried the same code with the WinUSB driver on a few other computers (Win XP SP3, Win7 x64) and they both returned the error "A device attached to the system is not functioning." when trying to use CreateFile to get a handle to the USB device.

The devicePath was found successfully, so I'm not sure why it cannot connect to the device.  Furthermore, the device manager states that my device is working properly.  I'm curious if I'm missing something when compiling the code?  I would guess that my development computer has something installed on it that the other computers do not?  Or perhaps it's a power setting and the device is going to sleep (although I've fooled around with the Power Options on each computer to no avail).

Does anyone have any ideas?  I've compiled under Visual Studio 2008, and have installed the Microsoft C++ 2008 Redistributable Package on the computers that I've tested on.

Thanks,

Giawa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved:  The GUID that my driver was using was shared with another device on the system, which was returned instead of my device.  The device just happened to not be installed on my computer.  I've generated a new GUID and everything seems to work now.

Giawa